# Call function of a already deployed smart contract from within my smart contract

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, evm

i want to call the openTrade() function of this smart contract https://polygonscan.com/address/0xd8D177EFc926A18EE455da6F5f6A6CfCeE5F8f58#code (starts at line 371) from within my smart contract.

I have read about the ABI but this does not seem to work.
What steps do i need to take ?
Copy paste the whole smart contract into my visual studio code and import it into my contract?

How can i just call this specific function ?

Thank you so much guys !

Answer (score 1):

This is the [decription](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xd8D177EFc926A18EE455da6F5f6A6CfCeE5F8f58#code#L346) of the function you want to call:

```
  function openTrade(...) external notContract notDone { ... }
```

As you can see there is `notContract` modifier applied to this function. An this is implementation of the modifier:

```
modifier notContract(){ require(tx.origin == msg.sender); _; }
```

It means that `openTrade` function can not be called from the other contracts.